How to animate an Opacity transiiton in react-fiber/drei using <Text>
I want to animate an opacity transition from 0 to 1 using react-fiber/drei  component.
I tried using react-srping/three however it does not seem to work:
`import { useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import { Text } from "@react-three/drei";
import { animated, useSpring } from "@react-spring/three";

function Cube() {
    const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>(null);
    const styles = useSpring({
        from: {
          opacity: 0
        },
        to: {
          opacity: 1
        }, 
        delay: 1000,
      })

    
    return (
        <group>
          <Text
                position={[0, 0, 0]}
                fontSize={1}
                color="white"
                anchorX="center"
                anchorY="middle"
                fillOpacity={styles.opacity as any}
             >
           test
          </Text> 
        
        </group>
            
    
    
    );
  }`


React-spring/three does not seem to work? is there any other framework or do i have to program such an transition manually ?

I don’t use Spring too often, but you can achieve that easily with useFrame hook.
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, Text } from '@react-three/drei';

function AnimatedText() {
  const textRef = useRef();
  const textOpacity = useRef(0);
  const directionRef = useRef(1);

  useFrame(() => {
    textOpacity.current += 0.01 * directionRef.current;
    if (textOpacity.current >= 1 || textOpacity.current <= 0) {
      directionRef.current *= -1;
    }
    textRef.current.material.opacity = textOpacity.current;
    textRef.current.material.needsUpdate = true;
  });

  return (
    <Text
      ref={textRef}
      position={[0, 0, 0]}
      fontSize={1}
      color="red"
      transparent
      opacity={0}
    >
      Hello
    </Text>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={2} />
      <AnimatedText />
      <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
  );
}


it does not work that way as textRef.current.material.opacity does not seem to have effects on the opacity.
in this case above, i just used plane useState() and useFrame logic
