react-three-fiber opacity animation with useRef does not work
I want to change the opacity of a Three.js Mesh. I use React Three Fiber.
const planeRef = useRef<Mesh>(null);

  useFrame(() => {
    if(planeRef.current) {
        //@ts-ignore
        planeRef.current.material.opacity += 0.1
    }    
   })

return (
      <mesh ref={planeRef}>
        <Plane args={[5, 5]} position={[0, 0, -1]}>
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="white" opacity={0} transparent={true}/>
        </Plane>
      </mesh>

However, nothing happens. I don't understand why I can't access the mesh properties.

You got answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78604470/how-to-animate-an-opacity-transiiton-in-react-fiber-drei-using-text/78609487#78609487

you are referring to another question of mine

Solution :
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color("white"), opacity:0, transparent: true });
and then cast it into the <{geometry} material = {material}/>
you can now use the opacity or any other property with gsap
